# How to create a method to return 1 or 0 without using conditions?

Tags: java, c#, logic, logical-operators

I was asked a question in an interview to return 1 if provided 0 and return 0 if provided 1 without using conditions i.e if, ternary etc

Just to give you and idea below code without if's:

```
public int testMethod(int value){
    if(value==0) return 1;
    if(value==1) return 0;
    return 0;
}
```

[`Java Fiddle`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMbFJMXzlmZi1KZUk)

**UPDATE:**
Though @Usagi's Answer may seem the best fit with respect to the code I wrote .. but re-considering the question I re-analyzed the answers .. and @Sergio's answer seems the simplest and best fit ..

Comment: Without using conditions?  Meaning no `if` or ternary operators?

Comment: @HelderSepu did you read the question?

Comment: I updated your question to remove the language tags and made it language agnostic since the question doesn't say the language matters.  Did the interviewer give you a language constraint?  Otherwise @Usagi's answer is what I would have said.

Comment: What if the input is neither 0 nor 1?

Comment: @JNYRanger no language constraint .. though they are a Java base company but they were testing my logic .. Yes indeed i tried Usagi's answer it correct .. will mark it so in a while ..

Comment: Why was the now-deleted `return 1-value;` answer downvoted? With no specification of what to return for other input, that's completely correct and much simpler than the other answers.

Comment: This is very much *not* language-agnostic, because any solution depends heavily on how the integer data type is implemented. (At least, in the case where the input is not 1 or 0 as the example implies.)

Comment: If you're expected to return 0 on other input, you should explicitly say so (in fact, you should probably clarify even if 0 and 1 are the only valid input values). At the moment one can assume either that return statement in your code is simply there to get your code to compile or that it's there to intentionally deal with the other inputs.

Comment: @chepner I changed it back to language specific since all the answers use C# or Java anyways...

Comment: @Rafay please review my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45438784/how-to-create-a-method-to-return-1-or-0-without-using-conditions/48360970#48360970  The answer is downvoted, but I do not understand why, because it works for all int numbers.

Comment: @AlexanderI. Hello Alexander, I surely did not down-vote it ..maybe somebody spammed it ..

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you are given only 0 and 1 then this could be simpler:

`return 1 - value;`

Comment: Wow, great solution.

Comment: The simplest things are the most beautiful

Comment: ok i was banging my head on the wrong door .. this is a beautiful answer ..

Comment: I had abs(value-1) but this is simpler and much more elegant.

Answer (score 28):

```
public int testMethod(int value) {
  return 1 - (value % 2); // or 1 - (value & 1)
}
```

This could use to switch between any value and 0, EG 3:

```
public int testMethod3(int value) {
  return 3 - (value % 4);
}
```

And just to cover the `return 0` at the end of the sample in the question:

```
private static final int[] VALUES = { 1, 0 };

public int testMethod(int value) {
    try {
        return VALUES[value];
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doh, you beat me to it!

Comment: Oh nice .. never thought of it this way .. :)

Answer (score 24):

We can use the xor operator here. Xor is "exclusive or" and returns a 0 when there are two or zero 1's and returns 1 if there's exactly one 1.  It does this on every bit of the integer.

So for example, the binary 1001 ^ 1000 = 0001 as the first bit has two 1's, so 0, the next two have no 1's, so zero, and the final bit only has one 1, outputting a 1.

```
public int testMethod(int value){
    return value ^ 1;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the better answer since XOR is logically equivalent to the inequality operator when operating on boolean  values.

Comment: This does not give the same answer as the original code for inputs other than 0 and 1.

Answer (score 14):

My original answer

```
public int TestMethod(int value)
{
     return Convert.ToInt32(!Convert.ToBoolean(value));
}
```

---

and the modified one as suggested by [@The Photon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630971/the-photon)

```
public int TestMethod(int value)
{
     return Convert.ToInt32(value == 0);
}
```

---

A different approach is based on the behaviour of integer division in `C#` and avoiding the usage of exception handling.

```
public int TestMethod(int value)
{
    return 1 / ((10 * value) + 1);
}
```

---

All three methods will return the same results:

```
In | Out
-2 | 0 
-1 | 0
 0 | 1
 1 | 0
 2 | 0
```

Comment: The only answer not ignoring the last `return 0;`

Comment: Alternate: `return Convert.ToInt32(value==0);`

Comment: @ThePhoton `value==0` may hurts the constraint  _'without using conditions i.e if, ternary etc condition'_

Comment: @Martin,  `if` and `?:` statements are conditional statements that produce branches in the control flow. `==` is just an operator that produces a result --- it can't produce any branch in the control flow unless used with a conditional like `if` or `?:` (or short-circuit `&&` or `||` or probably something else I'm forgetting).

Answer (score 6):

You can use a bitwise operator like so:

```
value ^ 1
```

^ is the bitwise XOR operator which "copies the bit if it is set in one operand but not both". The representation of 1 and 0 in bits is as follows:

1 = 0000 0001

0 = 0000 0000

So when value = 1 you end up doing:

1 ^ 1 = (0000 0001) ^ (0000 0001) = 0000 0000 = 0 because since they share the same bits none of the bits are copied over.

Now if value = 0 you end up doing:

0 ^ 1 = (0000 0000) ^ (0000 0001) = 0000 0001 = 1 because the last bit is 1 in one of the operands but 0 in the other.

Comment: Consider inputs other than 0 or 1.

Comment: @ThePhoton: That wasn't the spec given by the op.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your language has something equivalent to `get the absolute value of this number` then something like:

```
public int testMethod(int value) {
  return Math.abs(value - 1);
}
```

would work.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, a try/catch function that **divides 0/value.**
- *Function works without using any Math library;*
- *Function works with ALL Integer values;*

```
public int MethodTest(int value)
{
     try
     {
         return (0/value);
     } 
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         return 1;
     }
}
```

The choice of value is done by triggering a Compile Error:
*A Zero divided by Zero usually triggers compile errors. Then returns 1;*
*A Zero divided any value different from Zero returns 0;*

Answer (score 3):

if there are no other inputs are allowed

```
    static int Test(int @value)
    {
        return (@value + 1) % 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please review my `C#` solution ([.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4y7G2h)):

```
private static int Calculate(int x)
{
    return ((-x ^ x) >> 31) + 1;
}
```

Examples:

```
Input: 0;           Output: 1;
Input: 1;           Output: 0;
Input: 64;          Output: 0;
Input: 65;          Output: 0;
Input: -100;        Output: 0;
Input: -101;        Output: 0;
Input: 102;         Output: 0;
Input: 888887;      Output: 0;
Input: 2147483647;  Output: 0;
Input: -2147483648; Output: 1;
```

It works for **all** `int` values (except `int.MinValue`).

Only logical and arithmetical operations without `Math`, `Convert`, etc. classes were used.

Explanation:

- Execute [XOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/xor-operator) operator for input number `x` and negative input number `-1 * x`. Described XOR operator for `C#` is `(-x ^ x)`
- XOR operator returns number with sign bit if `x` is non zero number (of course XOR with zero numbers returns 0)
- The sign bit is a left bit of the number. Sign bit is the 32'nd bit for `int` number.
- Execute [right-shift](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/right-shift-operator) operator and place sign bit on the first place for `int` number: `(-x ^ x) >> 31`
- `(-x ^ x) >> 31` returns -1 for any non zero `int` value (for zero number it returns 0)
- Add 1 and return result

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="475" src="https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/x4HCYj" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Hello Alexander, I surely did not down-vote it ..maybe somebody spammed it .

Answer (score 1):

Math.floor(1 / (1 + Math.abs(x)))

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is about calculate the bit-1 count.

```
public int testMethod(int value){
   //             v---  count = value == 0 ? 32 : [0,32)
   return Integer.bitCount(~value) / 32;
}
```

So the output should be as below:

```
//      v--- return 1
assert  testMethod(0) == 1; 

//      v--- return 0
assert  testMethod(nonZero) == 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

considering inputs are only `[1, 0]` it is also possible to make method to return the 0 to the power of input

In java

```
public int test(int value){
    return Math.pow(0,value);
}
```

Same logic can be applied for any other language

Answer (score 1):

Using bitwise xor is probably the most computationally efficient way to do it

`return value ^ 1`

Answer (score 1):

Number(!value)

it will return truthy or falsy value and converting it back into number, you will get 0 from 1 and 1 from 0.

Comment: method returns int not boolean

Comment: (!value)  returns boolean and you can convert that back to a number which is what Number function is doing here

Answer (score 0):

String trickery!

Java:

```
public int testMethod(int value) {
    return String.valueOf(value).substring(0, 1).indexOf('0') + 1;
}
```

C#:

```
public int testMethod(int value) {
    return value.ToString().Substring(0, 1).IndexOf('0') + 1;
}
```

This relies on indexOf/IndexOf returning -1 if no match was found.

Answer (score 0):

Given the range of value i is [0, 1]:

```
public int test(int i) {
    return !i;
}
```

This is pretty pointless...

Comment: Can you specify the language you are using. This will not compile in `C#` nor `Java`.

Answer (score 0):

Not efficient, but interesting one:

```java
public int neg(int n){
    return (int) Math.pow(0, n);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You are seeking some thing like this

```
var status = $_POST['status'];
status=='1'?'0':'1';
```

Comment: without using conditions i.e if, ternary etc. Your solution uses ternary operators